# Relative + base URL to absolute URL?

Tags: php

Basically, given a base URL like

```
file:///path/to/some/file.html
```

And a relative URL like

```
another_file.php?id=5
```

I want to get out

```
file:///path/to/some/another_file.php?id=5
```

I found [this script](http://publicmind.in/blog/urltoabsolute/) (which is the same as [this one](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/05/php_tip_how_convert_relative_url_absolute_url#Downloads)) but it doesn't seem to work on the `file://` scheme. I'm doing some local tests before I go live with my code, so I'd like to work on both `file://` and `http://`.

Any one know of a script/function that will do this?

In C#, I'd use [Uri(Uri base, string rel)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hst1w91.aspx).

---

The above is just an example. It should work on *any* URL that you could throw into `<a href="xxx">`.

---

This is the best I've got so far, but it won't handle `..` and probably a few other things:

```
function rel2abs($base, $rel) {
    if (parse_url($rel, PHP_URL_SCHEME) != '') return $rel;
    if ($rel[0]=='#' || $rel[0]=='?') return $base.$rel;
    $parse = parse_url($base);
    $path = preg_replace('#/[^/]*$#', '', $parse['path']);
    if ($rel[0] == '/') $path = '';
    $abs = (isset($path['host'])?$path['host']:'')."$path/$rel";
    $re = array('#(/\.?/)#', '#/(?!\.\.)[^/]+/\.\./#');
    for($n=1; $n>0; $abs=preg_replace($re, '/', $abs, -1, $n)) {}
    return $parse['scheme'].'://'.$abs;
}
```

Comment: cant u do a $result = str_replace("file.html","another_file.php?id=5","file:///path/to/some/file.html");

Comment: @EswarRajeshPinapala: No. This was an example, I was hoping for a more generic and flexible solution. The "relative" URL might have ".." (up one directory) in it, or it might be an absolute URL...or...any number of things that you could stuff into an `<a href="xxx">` and have it work.

Comment: See this implementation that tries to get every weird corner case right, including `file:///local/file` and `/local/path`: https://github.com/plaidfluff/php-urljoin

Comment: @fluffy Is that your lib? You should consider adding it to composer and using phpunit for your tests.

Comment: @mpen I'll consider it! I've never used either of those things. I just wanted to Get It Done. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get the URL broken into parts, and then split the 'path' portion on the forward-slash character.  That should allow you to re-assemble them and replace the last portion.

Something like this (psuedo-code, untested, not sure it's even valid PHP syntax):

```
$url_parts = parse_url($url_text);
$path_parts = explode('/', $url_parts[path]);

$new_url = $url_parts[scheme] + ":";

if ($url_parts[scheme] == "file") {
    $new_url .= '///';
} else {
    $new_url .= '//';
}

$new_url .= $url_parts[hostname] . '/';
for (int i = 0; i < count($path_parts) - 1; i++) {
    $new_url .= $path_parts[i] . "/";
} 

$new_url .= $REPLACEMENT_FILENAME
```

If need be, you can append the query string and/or anchor fragment (starts with #) at the end - see that parse_url() manual page for a list of the URL portions in its array.

Answer (score 2):

I've adapted Puggan Se's answer to handle certain relative URLs seen in HTML pages.

```
function url2absolute($baseurl, $relativeurl) {

    // if the relative URL is scheme relative then treat it differently
    if(substr($relativeurl, 0, 2) === "//") {
        if(parse_url($baseurl, PHP_URL_SCHEME) != null) {
            return parse_url($baseurl, PHP_URL_SCHEME) . ":" . $relativeurl;
        } else { // assume HTTP
            return "http:" . $relativeurl;
        }
    }

    // if the relative URL points to the root then treat it more simply
    if(substr($relativeurl, 0, 1) === "/") {
        $parts = parse_url($baseurl);
        $return = $parts['scheme'] . ":";
        $return .= ($parts['scheme'] === "file") ? "///" : "//";
        // username:password@host:port ... could go here too!
        $return .= $parts['host'] . $relativeurl;
        return $return;
    }

    // If the relative URL is actually an absolute URL then just use that
    if(parse_url($relativeurl, PHP_URL_SCHEME) !== null) {
        return $relativeurl;
    }

    $parts = parse_url($baseurl);

    // Chop off the query string in a base URL if it is there
    if(isset($parts['query'])) {
        $baseurl = strstr($baseurl,'?',true);
    }

    // The rest is adapted from Puggan Se

    $return = ""; // string to return at the end
    $minpartsinfinal = 3; // for everything except file:///
    if($parts['scheme'] === "file") {
        $minpartsinfinal = 4;
    }

    // logic for username:password@host:port ... query string etc. could go here too ... somewhere?      

    $basepath = explode('/', $baseurl); // will this handle correctly when query strings have '/'
    $relpath = explode('/', $relativeurl);

    array_pop($basepath);

    $returnpath = array_merge($basepath, $relpath);
    $returnpath = array_reverse($returnpath);

    $parents = 0;
    foreach($returnpath as $part_nr => $part_value) {
        /* if we find '..', remove this and the next element */
        if($part_value == '..') {
            $parents++;
            unset($returnpath[$part_nr]);
        } /* if we find '.' remove this element */
        else if($part_value == '.') {
            unset($returnpath[$part_nr]);
        } /* if this is a normal element, and we have unhandled '..', then remove this */
        else if($parents > 0) {
            unset($returnpath[$part_nr]);
            $parents--;
        }
    }
    $returnpath = array_reverse($returnpath);
    if(count($returnpath) < $minpartsinfinal) {
        return FALSE;
    }
        return implode('/', $returnpath);
}
```

Examples:

```
print url2absolute("file:///path/to/some/file.html", "another_file.php?id=5") . "<br>"; // original example
print url2absolute("file:///path/to/some/file.html", "../../../../../another_file.php?id=5") . "<br>"; // should be an error!
print url2absolute("http://path/to/some/file.html?source=this/one", "another_file.php?id=5") . "<br>"; // with query string on base URL
print url2absolute("http://path/to/some/file.html", "//other-path/another_file.php?id=5") . "<br>"; // scheme relative
```

Comment: The `$return` var underneath `if($parts['scheme'] === "file") {` and in the else condition are unused. You've overwritten it at the end.

Comment: Thanks Mark ... well spotted. Have updated the function.

Comment: You've still got unused vars: `$return`, `$minpartsinfinal`. You're also missing a `return` at the end. And your parentheses are unmatched now.

Comment: Corrected now. The last few lines of the code for the function had gone missing.

Comment: Still not a very well-written function. There's no need for so many calls to `parse_url`. There's quicker ways to get everything before the first `?` than using an improperly escaped regex (e.g. `strstr($baseurl,'?',true)`). The `$return` variable in the 2nd half is unneeded. You should return `false` or throw an exception in the event of an error, not return the string `"ERROR"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
/* strings from your exemple */
$base_url = "file:///path/to/some/file.html";
$relative_url = "another_file.php?id=5";

/* split up urls folder parts into an array */
$base_url_parts = explode('/', $base_url);
$relative_parts = explode('/', $relative);

/* remove last element (in this case "file.html") */
array_pop($base_url_parts);

/* merge absolute_url from base and relative */
$absolute_url_parts = array_merge($base_url_parts, $relative_parts);

/* reverser the list before the search of '..' */
$absolute_url_parts = array_reverse($absolute_url_parts);

/* count of current number of unhandled '..' */
$parent_folder_count = 0;

/* loop throught all elements looking for '..' */
foreach($absolute_url_parts as $part_nr => $part_value)
{
    /* if we find '..', remove this and the next element */
    if($part_value = '..')
    {
        $parent_folder_count++;
        unset($absolute_url_parts[$part_nr]);
    }

    /* if we find '.' remove this element */
    else if($part_value = '.')
    {
        unset($absolute_url_parts[$part_nr]);
    }

    /* if this is a normal element, and we have unhandled '..', then remove this */
    else if($parent_folder_count > 0)
    {
        unset($absolute_url_parts[$part_nr]);
        $parent_folder_count--;
    }

    /* else: keep it */
}

/* restore the order by reversing again */
$absolute_url_parts = array_reverse($absolute_url_parts);

/* restore the list to a string again */
$absolute_url = implode('/', $absolute_url_parts);

/* done */
?>
```

Comment: you may want to add exception for hrefs starting whit '?', '#', 'javascripts:', 'maito:', '[a-z]+://'

Comment: where do you even use `$relative_url`? this doesn't seem to work at all for me.

Comment: sorry, forgot the array_push, edit it soon, hmm, or a array_merge whould be better

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest solution would be to use the [dirname()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) function.

```
$url = 'file:///path/to/some/file.html';
$rel = 'another_file.php?id=5';

$final = dirname($url).'/'.$rel;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ab="file:///path/to/some/file.html";
$rel="another_file.php?id=5";

$exab=explode("/",$ab);
$exab[count($exab)-1]=$rel;

$newab=implode("/",$exab);
```

Probably not the most elegant solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
$file1 = "file://path/to/some/file.html";
$file2 = "anotherfile?q=1";

$newurl = substr_replace($file1, $file2, strrpos($file1, "/")+1);
```

http://codepad.org/370Yp1M7

Comment: Too simple. Won't work on rel-URLs like `../cheese.aspx` or `http://google.com/imnotactuallyrelative.kittens`

Comment: perhaps you should give some more specific examples of what you want then

Comment: Updated question. Anything that can fit in `<a href="xxx">`.